# how to pass value betweeen two tab in android

Tags: android-tabhost

I have followed the tutorial for android tab host and been able to run on emulator. Now what I want to do is just implement a text box and button in one tabview. As soon as user enter in text box and press button the value entered in text box shouls pass to second tab and I can use that value for further calculations.

Please guide me how to do this?
Thanks,
Alok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you should to do is to declare a global variable:

```
class foobarApp extends Application {

  private String txtValue;

  public String getTxtValue(){
    return txtValue;
  }
  public void setTxtValue(String aString){
    txtValue= aString;
  }
}
```

So, when the user presses the button:

```
foobarApp myApp = ((foobarApp)getApplicationContext());
setTxtValue(myTextEdit.getText());
```

And then, when the second tab loaded, you can get your value by doing this:

```
foobarApp myApp = ((foobarApp)getApplicationContext());
theOtherEditText.setText(myApp.getTxtValue());
```